# Writing files to Android Phone SD card over SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, android, rsync

I successfully set up SSHDroid on my phone so I could both login and use rsync to copy files FROM the phone to the computer. However, when I try to push files back the other way I get the error:

```
$rsync -vaz -e "ssh -p $port" /data/audio $server:/storage/3201-D8A1/audio

mkdir "/storage/3***-****/audio/" failed: Permission denied (13)
```

I tried logging into the phone over ssh and running the command

```
chmod a+w .
```

which doesn't give any error messages. But the folder status remains unchanged.

```
drwxr-xr-x 14 root everybody 128K 2019-04-18 18:36 .
```

I also tried changing my ssh name to "everybody" But this also failed.

```
SSHDroid
Use 'root' as username
Default password is 'admin'
everybody@***** password: 
sending incremental file list
books/
rsync: recv_generator: mkdir "/storage/3***-****/audio/books" failed: Permission denied (13)
*** Skipping any contents from this failed directory *
```

**

I verified I have write access to the directory on the phone, but it doesn't work over SSH no matter what I do.

Edit: It is an SD Card. I have write access to the internal storage.

Android Version 8.0.0

Comment: Is that a link to an SD card? And what version of Android is your phone using? You may wish to update (edit) your question with this information.

Comment: Yes it is an SD card. I tried to put files on /root/sdcard and it seemed to work the first try. However, it only worked for 1 second before the computer hard froze! Ctrl-Alt-F1 and all the other hotkeys did nothing. I had to hold the power button. This has happened before for me when trying to rsync to my phone. I wonder if it's a kernel bug.